# I need help understanding python function return

Tags: python, function

In the python book I'm reading, in the function section it says "Once the program execution returns from  the local scope is destroyed."

I understand scope, but what is meant by 'when program execution returns from .' Is the return point the line that follows the function call?

```py
def spam():
    eggs = 99
    bacon()
    print (eggs)
           
def bacon():
    ham = 101
    eggs = 0

spam()
```

Comment: Please reindent your code. Indenting matters, especially in Python.

Comment: Even if you fix indentation, neither function returns anything

Comment: Please double-check that quote, that's not a valid sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following program:

```
def is_odd(a: int) -> bool:
    if a % 2 == 1:
        return true
    else:
        return false

x = is_odd(3)
y = is_odd(4)
```

When you think about 'program execution' what you need to think about is the order that the code is executed in. In this case:

- `def ...` -> the code defines a new function `is_odd`. It captures the code inside this function as part of that definition, but does not execute that code.
- `x = is_odd(3)` -> the code now *calls* the defined function `is_odd()` with the parameter `3`.
  -> `if a % 2 == 1` -> the code makes an equality check. `a` in this case is `3` because that is the parameter that was passed in. The code will first apply the modulo operator to `a`, resulting in a value `1`. It then applies the equality operation to `1` and `1`, which results in `true`. It then makes the equality check `if`, and since it is false, it skips to the `else` block.
- Inside `else` it returns `true`. We then return to the line `is_odd(3)`. The result, `false` is assigned to `x`.
- Then it executes `y = is_odd(4)`. The process above is repeated, but `is_odd()` returns `false`, which is then assigned to y.

So, essentially, the 'program execution' is each incremental step the program takes. When we talk about 'calling' or 'returning from' from a function we are really jumping to a different point in our source code. But as my example demonstrates, the return point is exactly where you left: it isn't the next line, but literally the point where the function call was made. When it is trying to interpret that line, say `x = is_odd(3)`, it has to first evaluate what `is_odd(3)` is, so that it can assign that value to `x`. That is when it calls the `is_odd()` function, and takes the return result and converts `x = is_odd(3)` to `x = true`, which it then, in turn, evaluates causing a new variable to be assigned in that scope.

Only once there is no more evaluation to be done does the program move on to the next line.